# A problem from Flink Training tutorial: LongRidesSolution.scala

Tags: apache-flink

What this function(ProcessElement) will do is pretty clear:
Based on the keyed stream(keyed by rideId), it will iterate all the elements whose rideId belongs to that key,it will update the state based on the condition

```
override def processElement(ride: TaxiRide,
                                context: KeyedProcessFunction[Long, TaxiRide, TaxiRide]#Context,
                                out: Collector[TaxiRide]): Unit = {
      val timerService = context.timerService
      if (ride.isStart) {
        // the matching END might have arrived first; don't overwrite it
        if (rideState.value() == null) {
          rideState.update(ride)
        }
      }
      else {
        rideState.update(ride)
      }

      timerService.registerEventTimeTimer(ride.getEventTime + 120 * 60 * 1000)
    }
```

The Timer will trigger once the watermark reaches to the timestamp

```
    override def onTimer(timestamp: Long,
                         ctx: KeyedProcessFunction[Long, TaxiRide, TaxiRide]#OnTimerContext,
                         out: Collector[TaxiRide]): Unit = {
      val savedRide = rideState.value

      if (savedRide != null && savedRide.isStart) {
        out.collect(savedRide)
      }
      rideState.clear()
    }
```

The Problem is: If the End record comes first,and then based on the logic, it will not update the ride state(related key),then it will trigger after 2 hours, then it will not collect and will not emit the record, but what if this record meets our requirement? ==> the start time of the record happened more than 2 hours ago? I think there should be more logic to deal with that

Comment: Interesting question! I'm glad this exercise got you thinking. Maybe we can rework that exercise a bit to clarify this point.

Answer (score 0):

If the END record is processed before the START record, then it could be that the START record arrives very late, and when it does arrive it supplies evidence that this ride lasted for more than two hours.

However, the goal of this exercise is not to find all rides that last for more than two hours, but rather to flag, in real-time, rides that should have ended by now (because they started more than two hours ago), but haven't. Since these rides you ask about have ended, it's debatable whether they merit alerts.

You've raised an interesting point that should probably be added to the exercise discussion page.

Comment: I saw the comment from the source code: // the matching END might have arrived first; don't overwrite it,  ===> It raised a question to me, otherwise i may not question that condition haha

Comment: Also from your words _If the END record is processed before the START record, then it could be that the START record arrives very late, and when it does arrive it supplies evidence that this ride lasted for more than two hours._, i would say as  long as the end record comes before the start one, it will not emit that record, no matter the start one was more than 2 hours before end record, which results in losing some necessary data

Comment: Whenever the END event arrives first, this cannot be an ongoing ride. End of story.

Comment: Just by the way, compared to the previous version of the training tutorial, NearestTaxiSolution.scala,CheckpointedLongRidesSolution.scala,LongRidesCEPSolution.scala are gone, the description from the source code is not that detailed, a bit of rough,could you plz tell me where they are? many thinks!

Comment: The older exercises are in https://github.com/ververica/flink-training-exercises.

Comment: And the repo that builds the old website is at https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training/tree/gh-pages

Comment: Thanks!, I will build that repo

Comment: Just By the way, how can i build this repo? github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training/tree/gh-pages,thx!

Comment: Rather than building it, maybe just access it from https://web.archive.org/web/20190317011721/https://training.ververica.com/

Comment: It's built via preview.sh, which simply invokes jekyll, which you'd have to install. Which in turn requires ruby, and can get messy to get working properly.